# Content publishing and confirming comment via email in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users, emails, importing-exporting

I want to provide following functionality:

1. When a user sends a mail to publisher@mysite.com, the subject of email become title of a blog post and body of email become body of blog post and the post should be published if the mail is done by admin
2. If the mail is not done by admin then a mail should go to admin notifying same and if admin replies "publish" then it should be published else it should not be published

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no module for this functionality afaik.

To implement this one,

- You need to pull the mails from server
- Processing the mails and performing other operations like checking whether the user is an admin
- After the processing create the content
- Finally add a cron job to perform this operation regularly

This [article](http://peterthorndycraft.com/tutorial/mailhandler) provides info about how to achieve this feature in drupal 7 with combination of several modules.

However authenticating using the sender's mail will be a security risk. For example if the admin mail ID is exposed then anyone can send mails as admin by altering the header information.

Comment: thanks for the link, i was also thinking about the same security risk, any better alternative to go?

Comment: Sorry :( I don't have any idea about that.